# How to get the list of hyperlinks of a webpage in Webkit/Gtk?

Tags: webkit, gtk

In here a window is being created and a webpage is generated:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WebKitWebView *webView;
    GtkWidget *main_window;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    if (!g_thread_supported())
        g_thread_init(NULL);
#ifndef GTK_API_VERSION_2
    disablePlugin("Shockwave Flash");
#endif
    main_window = createWindow(&webView);
    gchar *uri =(gchar*)(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "http://www.google.com/");
    gchar *fileURL = filenameToURL(uri);
    webkit_web_view_load_uri(webView, fileURL ? fileURL : uri);
    g_free(fileURL);
    gtk_widget_grab_focus(GTK_WIDGET(webView));
    gtk_widget_show_all(main_window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

And here is where a notification says that a page is being loaded:

```
void FrameLoaderClient::postProgressFinishedNotification()
{
    WebKitWebView* webView = getViewFromFrame(m_frame);
    WebKitWebViewPrivate* privateData = webView->priv;
    if (!privateData->disposing)
    g_signal_emit_by_name(webView, "load-finished", m_frame);
}
```

Now after the page is loaded, I want to get the list of focusable nodes such as hyperlinks, checkbox.

how can i do it?

Comment: I have found the python code for it:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=867381         which is: import urllib 
mypath = "http://ubuntuforums.org" 
mylines = urllib.urlopen(mypath).readlines() 
for item in mylines: 
if  "http://" in item: 
print item[item.index("http://"):]
   I just need to figure out how to do that in C.

Comment: can anyone help me in this!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to look at is how to access the DOM from WebKit. WebKit has a `webkit_web_view_get_dom_document()` (http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-get-dom-document) which returns an instance of `WebKitDOMDocument` (https://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk/ProgrammingGuide/Reference). This will give you direct access to the DOM and has methods like `webkit_dom_document_get_elements_by_tag_name()` to query the DOM. You could do something like this:

```
WebKitDomDocument *dom = webkit_web_view_get_dom_document(webview);
WebKitDOMNodeList *elements = webkit_dom_document_get_elements_by_tag_name(dom, "a");
int i = 0;
WebKitDOMElement *anchor = NULL;
for (; i < webkit_dom_node_list_get_length(elements); i++) {
     anchor = (WebKitDOMElement *)webkit_dom_node_list_item(elements, i);
}
```

This is not perfect code, but you should get the idea from it. If you want to take a look at a somewhat comprehensive sample look here: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-7533.16/gtk/tests/testdomdocument.c. Hope that helps.